# I am trying to make p2p network over tcp

Tags: c++, delphi, p2p

I am using Indy components pack for it. Actually I am succeed to make p2p network over udp and it's still working now, but with udp I need to send some ping package every time, otherway the router will remove the virtual port in mapping port list! For video or sound or gaming project over udp is the best way but for my project I need it over tcp.

How I did: I have 1 server machine owned a real ip, all clients before swiching to p2p mode need to send package to the server, and now server know the all clients virtual port (out port) maked on the router, if some client want to send data to another client, he just need to send data to another client ip and virtual port on router. Router can map it automatically.

I was try same way in tcp , the client was send data to another client ip and virtual port (on router) but tcp client component can't receive it! With udp it can receive

Why over tcp p2p topology different then udp

Or how can I send data to server machine using with idtcpserver component for create a virtual port on the router

Comment: Or tcp client cannot connect to another client :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind `sockets` with TCP. UDP are not bound the same way.
[Difference between TCP and UDP](https://serverfault.com/q/8981/35330)

In the package that you have (if you provide the name of it you might get more help) there should be some sort of `connection / socket / binding` to the client that is connecting to your server. It is that connection that you need to send data to.

Comment: I already know difference of udp and tcp. My problem is I have 1 tcpserver under of NAT and the tcpserver port is 1234 but behind of NAT. How can I get a virtual port for mapped with my tcpserver port ? Any idea?

Comment: You have to configure the NAT to forward the traffic to your machine. The machine *behind* the NAT is allowed to create connections with machines *outside* the NAT but **not** the other way around.